# Contour plots of noisy data - gridding and averaging

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to make a contour plot from a dataframe in which the x and y coordinates are unevenly spaced and sometimes overlap and the z coordinate is noisy:

```
        x                y                 z
1     15.4707          174.6779          1592.811638
2     15.4707          171.3179          1304.953183
3     61.6107          108.2379          1687.233377
4     46.3707          151.6929          1688.368690
5     30.7107          124.5429          1339.451757
6     31.1307          202.8704          1616.756963
7     0.2307          141.5029          1620.288736
8     15.4707          141.9054          1167.798302
9     46.3707           72.0729          1687.546227
10    15.4707          212.6929          638.059709
```

What I'd like to do is to define a grid in x and y whose gridelines pass coordinates, say

```
x=[7.5, 22.5, 37.5, 52.5]
y=[60, 120, 180, 240]
```

In every grid section, I then take the average of the z values and make a new dataframe where the x and y columns are the centres of the grid sections and the z column is the aforementioned average. The dataframe should look something like

```
      x           y            z
1     15          90           1621.1
2     30          150          1444.2
3     45          210          1651.7
```

From this stage it easy to get a contour plot using `matplotlib.contourf` or similar, but how can do this type of gridding and averaging? Is there an elegant way to do it in Pandas or other python packages?

Comment: This is a whole art, but I'd start with griddata: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html

Comment: Thanks but it seems this method is only able to interpolate the data onto a regular grid - can't see any way to average existing values on a user-defined grid from the documentation.

Comment: Another way of thinking about this is to imagine a 2d histogram except that the color bar is not the point count in the bin but the average value of z in it.

Comment: The grid in griddata doesn't have to be even, but it does have to be rectangular.  If you just want to histogram, you can just use `numpy.histogram2d` with the data values as weights or scipy.stats.binned_statistic